# In Mac OS X, how to automatically connect to samba server when machine starts?

Tags: macos, boot, samba

In Mac OS X, how do I automatically connect to a remote hard drive on a samba server when machine starts?  I normally manually do `Finder` -> `Go` -> `Connect to server` (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) -> type in `smb://foobar.com` -> select partition and directory.  Is it possible to have it connected automatically every time the machine starts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be enough to add the volume to your *Login Items*, which can be found under *System Preferences » Accounts*.

[image]