# mac osx 10.9, Automatically connect to network drive on startup, wake up

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks

I have a shared folder in the Ubuntu 13.10 server. I can connect to this shared folder from my mac os using "connect to server"

```
smb://ubuntunas/download
```

I dont want to do it manually everytime. is it possible to connect to it at startup

there's already a similar question asked. but still couldn't get it working.

[In Mac OS X, how to automatically connect to samba server when machine starts?](https://superuser.com/questions/437386/in-mac-os-x-how-to-automatically-connect-to-samba-server-when-machine-starts)

System Preferences » Accounts,  i cannot find "Accounts" in System Preferences. I am using osx mavericks.

Comment: It might have been renamed, look under System Preferences > "Users And Groups", should be the first item in 4th row.

Comment: @nappo thank you so much, it is renamed to "users and groups". please answer my question, i will pick it as answer.